# How to add .mdf file in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, blazor

I am unable to find `.mdf` file type in new item of Visual Studio 2019 while developing a Blazor server app.

Comment: It would exist in your `%UserProfile%\xxx.mdf`  like: `C:\Users\<Username>\xxx.mdf`.

Answer (score 3):

For whatever it's worth... this is what I did to add an **mdf** database file to my `Visual Studio 2019` solution:

First I had to install this `nuget` package: [Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact)

[image]

Then I added the **mdf** file to the `solution` like this:
[image]

To *view* and *update* the **mdf** database - open the `Server Explorer`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following steps:

1. Go to Tools -> Options
2. Select Database Tools -> Data Connections and provide the Sql Server Instance Name 
       with the instance name of your database.
3. Then go to Services by pressing Win + R and Services.msc
4. Select the SQL Server (the instance name), right click and select Properties
5. Then in the properties window of the service go to Log On tab and select Local System account

Answer (score 0):

To add .mdf files you should have selected **.NET desktop development and Data storage and processing** while installation of visual studio 2019.

if you have not selected then you need to launch **Visual Studio launcher** and choose to modify and select it.

After updation you should see .mdf file option while adding a new item in any project.

**Note:** this option you will see if you add a .Net Framework project but .netcore.
But once you add the file , it can be moved to any type of project.